# MYSQL won't allow me to create a table

Tags: mysql-workbench

Im new to SQL and when trying to create a table in a database it shows where I can type but it won't let me input and characters to name it. I am also using a Mac if that makes a difference.

[image]

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling but still getting the same issue.

Comment: What application is that, MySQL Workbench?

Comment: Yes, MySQL Workbench

Comment: You have to raise this as a bug with mysql and installa newer version of mysql workbench if possible and hope for the best. Or replace mysql workbench with a different mysql gui

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL Workbench not showing Apply and Revert buttons while creating a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78239093/mysql-workbench-not-showing-apply-and-revert-buttons-while-creating-a-table)