# MySQL Workbench not showing Apply and Revert buttons while creating a table

Tags: mysql-workbench

I'm trying to create a table using MySQL workbench, but the Apply and revert buttons are not showing. I also can't type in a name for the table.

[image: mysql-workbenc-for-mac-not-showing-apply-and-revert-buttons-while-creating-a-table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest release of MySQL Workbench (8.0.36) on MacOS Sonoma has a UI bug which was reported on 2024-01-16:

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=113653

There are also numerous duplicate reports of the same bug.

I downloaded the previous release, 8.0.34, and it works correctly. The table name and Apply button appear as normal.

I really get the feeling MySQL doesn't put any priority on their Workbench application. I don't use it because it has so many bugs like this one.

Comment: Thank you. I downloaded 8.0.34 and the buttons show!

Comment: Yep! I recommend do not upgrade MySQL Workbench until they fix the bug I linked to. You may log into your bugs.mysql.com account and click the "Affects Me" button to raise its priority, and subscribe to bug to be notified of updates.