How do I edit tables through the UI on MySQL Workbench on MacOS?
I'm guessing this is either something I'm completely overlooking, or this is a poorly placed button. I want to create/edit tables through the UI in MySQL Workbench on MacOS. In the table editor, I don't see anywhere that will allow me to save any changes made.
Creating a table also seems pointless as there does not seem to be any field to name a table when creating it on top of no save button. I can create and modify tables fine by running CREATE ALTER statements; at this point it's more curiosity and/or frustration that I am trying to figure out how to do it through the UI (it'd also save me some time). Picture below of what my screen currently looks like when I am trying to modify a table (no buttons at all are in the blacked out portions of the picture).


Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78239093/mysql-workbench-not-showing-apply-and-revert-buttons-while-creating-a-table/78239637#78239637

It seems minimized somehow, as it is suppose to be right here :

You could try adjusting this vertical slider below this (Action Output) and see if its mushed down somehow and thus hidden?  Hover over the line seperating these containers until the icon changes to a slider and see if adjusting the height of those containers helps display it.


Thanks for helping. Doesn't look like there is anything there for me to adjust. I just see the Action Output box and a vertical slider in between that and the edit box above. I logged into my database to make sure I had privileges (even though I can create and edit tables in the query console) and I have CREATE and ALTER privileges so I'm not sure what this is. Seems like a bug or poor design. Very frustrating.

Interesting, and annoying, I mean you could hand type the alter statements but it sort of defeats the whole purpose of a GUI advantage.  Is it possible that the Mac is an M1 variety that you could dual boot with windows or linux just to see if shows up in those for testing purposes, as Workbench does work in all of them, but NGL I swear I saw someone else with an Apple have this issue months ago if I recall.
